# how to troubleshoot "Communications link failure" error with Cloud Data Fusion

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-data-fusion, proxysql

I have two GCP projects. A testing environment, built from scratch and a production environment with an already existing Cloud SQL for MySQL instance. My goal is to set a replication pipeline with Data Fusion to replicate some MySQL table.

On the testing environment I'm able to connect data fusion to MySQL. It is not working on the production environment. I have the following error:

```
Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

This error message is pretty mysterious to me. The two environment are setup exactly the same way as far as I can see so I don't understand where is this error coming from. What can I do to better understand what's behind this error?

my setup is one Cloud SQL for MySQL instance on Private IP, on VM with proxy SQL, one Private Cloud fusion instance.

Comment: So where is your Data Fusion instance located? Like are you running the data fusion instance on prod project and you want to pull data from production and insert it into testing?